# Заполненить 3 input а из одной кнопки

Tags: javascript, html

Прошлый раз задавал подобный вопрос на что участник этого сообщества , наш друг Igor дал верный ответ.

```js
function addTextToInput(anElement) {
  var text = document.getElementById('jaloby').value;
  if (text != "")
    text += ",";
  text += anElement.innerText;
  document.getElementById('jaloby').value = text;
}
```

```html
<input id="jaloby" />
<input id="obekt" />
<input id="diagnoz" />
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="addTextToInput(this)">1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="addTextToInput(this)">2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="addTextToInput(this)">3</button>
```

С вышеописанного кода видно что кнопки заполняют `value` поля с айдишником `jaloby`. А теперь встала задача чтоб они заполнили одновременно все три поля которые есть. Как можно указать js чтоб он заполнял все три поля в моем случаи. Пробовал всякую всячину не помогло так как с js не дружу к сожалению (

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/683159/178988

Comment: Да именно там и ответили правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function addTextToInputs(anElement) {
  [jaloby, obekt, diagnoz].forEach(input => {
      let text = input.value;
      if (text)
        text += ",";
      text += anElement.innerText;
      input.value = text;
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="jaloby" />
<input id="obekt" />
<input id="diagnoz" />
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="addTextToInputs(this)">1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="addTextToInputs(this)">2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="addTextToInputs(this)">3</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.